# How to I create code that can sum an unknown number columns and fixed number of rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that will be able to add any number of columns in a spreadsheet. I am well aware this can be hard-coded, however I am trying to write code that can work with any number of columns without needing to change the code everytime.

This is what I'd like to output (Totals are listed at the bottom of each column):

```
  A   |   B                                        A   |   B   |   C
----- | -----                                    ----- | ----- | -----
  20  |   30                                       20  |   30  |    4
----- | -----                                    ----- | ----- | -----
   3  |   45      Now another column is added:      3  |   45  |   55    
----- | -----                                    ----- | ----- | -----
  13  |    4                                       13  |    4  |   15
-------------                                    ---------------------
  36  |   79                                       36  |   79  |   74
```

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Range("b1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("b1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Dim vStartRow As Integer
    vStartRow = 2
    Dim vEndRow As Integer
    vEndRow = ActiveCell.Row
    Dim vStartColumn As Integer
    vStartColumn = 2
    Dim vEndColumn As Integer
    vEndColumn = ActiveCell.Column
    Cells(vEndRow + 1, vEndColumn).Formula = "=sum(b" & vStartRow & ":b" & vEndRow & ")"
    Cells(vEndRow, vEndColumn + 1).Select
End Sub
```

Note: I would like each calculation to happen when a button is clicked instead of all at once

Comment: Since there are plenty of examples on SO of how to find the last column (and last row) dynamically, what, exactly is your problem?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have not found any examples that answers my specific requirements. If you know of some, a link would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You want code that specifies a formula to do the sum under all the rows of each column. Not code that does the sum as the title suggest. Please edit the title to make it clear what you want to be done.

Comment: If the answers posted below are "*too complex for what I need*", then I suspect you may not understand how the code you are using is working.  That being the case, you may need to hire someone to develop and maintain the process you require.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am trying to teach myself VBA and macros. The answer that I was given below was above my current level of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Use `R1C1` notation like this.

```
With Sheet1 '/* Change with your actual sheet code name */
    Dim lc As Long, fr As Long
    Dim r As Range, c As Range

    fr = 3 '/* change it to your actual static row
    lc = .Cells(fr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set r = .Range("A1", .Cells(3, lc))
    For Each c In r.Offset(fr).Resize(1)
        If Not c.HasFormula Then
            c.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & fr & "]C:R[-1]C)"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Should reside in a `Module` then assign in a `Button`.

Comment: While it looks good. This is a tad too complex for what I need. Is there anyway to do it, continuing in the fashion I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function that I have created for the output that you are looking for in your above example. This code will add any number of columns and will give you the total in 5th row.You can implement this function on a button.

```
Sub AddColumns()

Dim ColumnCount As Integer
Dim Rownumber As Integer
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
Dim TotalValue As Integer

ColumnCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
For ColumnNumber = 1 To ColumnCount
TotalValue = 0
    For Rownumber = 2 To 4
        TotalValue = TotalValue + Cells(Rownumber, ColumnNumber)
    Next Rownumber
    Cells(5, ColumnNumber) = TotalValue
Next ColumnNumber

End Sub
```